# In Eclipse, how can I export a package and all sub-packages as a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to export a specific package and its sub-packages as a non-runnable jar in Eclipse. I right click the package I want to export and hit "Export". However, when I export the jar, it only exports the top level package I've selected and all of its classes.

What I want is to export all sub-packages with it automatically as well. The only way I've been able to do this so far is to actually select each sub-package (and their sub-packages, etc...) for exporting as well. Is there any way to select all sub-packages for exporting as well automatically?

An example (with image):

I want to export the "bar1" package as a jar. I right click the bar1 package, click "Export" and select JAR. However, bar1's sub-package, "util". Is not selected by default and will not be exported. If I wanted to export bar1's sub-packages, I would need to select them individually. This is a pain if there are a lot of packages. Is there any way to have Eclipse add the "util" sub-package for exporting when I try to export the "bar1" package?

[image]

Comment: From Package-explorer, Right-click. Choose Export...   Then, choose Java / Jar file. Then Next> will allow you to choose what you want

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. The problem is, as I've said, that I'm only able to export the top level package and not its sub packages (and their sub packages) without selecting all of them individually. I'm asking if there's a way to select all sub packages automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have is correct and there is not a lot of automation or easier way beside clicking your way through it to select a specific package and sub-packages. However,  I think you can use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to do this for you which is much automated and easier. Here is how you can select specific package in ant :

```
<dirset dir="aDirectory">
    <include name="a/package/**"/>
    <exclude name="**/package/to/exclude**"/>
</dirset>
```

Comment: Alright, if this is the only way I'll look into it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file->export->JAR file, there you may select "Export generated class files and sources" and make sure that your project is selected, and all folder under there are also! Also, make sure they are in the Build Configuration -> Order and Export area, and they are checked for export.

If all else fails, try [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/). It detects all dependencies and automatically bundles them into the JAR. In Eclipse you can use FatJar by using the Build Fat Jar option for Java projects.

Comment: FatJar is an enhanced JAR export plugin for Eclipse, give it a try.

Comment: I know what FatJar is, but the question is asking something different.

Comment: Fail. FatJar doesn't check dependencies properly. It blindly exports everything on the classpath, even tons of classes/packages that aren't even related.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to set the Package Explorer view to Flat instead of Hierarchical (triangle -> Package presentation -> Flat)

Then select all packages that start with `bar1`, right-click, export.